# Splitting sf layer into individual segments like QGIS explodelines tool does

Tags: r, sf, rqgis, lwgeom

I have loaded my road network data into `R` as an `sf` object. I would like to split each line into individual segments (split at each vertex).

I have used the `qgisprocess` package and it works. Here is the code below:

```
roads_exploded <- st_read(qgis_run_algorithm("native:explodelines", INPUT = my_route)$OUTPUT)
```

My problem is that this is part of a `shiny` app that will run on a server without `QGIS` installation.
So, I have to implement this using other packages.

Here is what I have tried so far to no avail:

(1) Using `lwgeom` package:

```
vertices <- my_route %>% st_cast("MULTIPOINT") %>% st_cast("POINT") %>% pull(geom)
roads_exploded <- st_split(my_route, vertices)
```

(2) Using a custom function that exlusively uses `sf`:

```
explodelines <- function(lines){ 
 split_lines <- lapply(1:nrow(lines), function(i){
    current_line <- lines[i, ]
    current_vertices <- st_nearest_points(current_line, vertices)  # Find nearest vertices
    split_points <- st_coordinates(current_vertices)[, 1:2]  # Extract coordinates
    
    if(nrow(current_vertices) > 0) {  # Split if vertices are found
      segments <- st_line_sample(current_line, density = max(1, nrow(current_vertices)))  # Ensure enough segments
      split_geoms <- st_split(segments, split_points)
    } else {
      split_geoms <- current_line  # Keep original geometry if no vertices
    }
    
    # Combine split geometries, preserving attributes
    split_lines_i <- st_sfc(split_geoms)
    st_set_geometry(lines[i, ], split_lines_i)
  })
  
  split_lines <- do.call(rbind, split_lines)
  
  return(split_lines)
}
roads_exploded <- explodelines(my_route)
```

Can you help me find where the issue is?

Comment: Hi! Did you check the R package sfnetworks?

Comment: I figured out I could just use `sf::intersection()` but this is super slow for a fairly large dataset. So, any suggestions of other alternatives would be welcome.

Comment: It's quite difficult to provide more details if you don't post a reproducible example